# Eclipse Import > Git Option Not Available

Tags: eclipse, git, import, repository

I am trying to import a git project, but the git option is not available under "Import." I have Eclipse 3.7.2, and EGit is already installed. I've done Git imports before on this version of Eclipse, but I didn't have this issue before. I am on a different computer, reinstalling everything, and trying to get my old project to run

Comment: should we assume you've already cloned the git repository?

Comment: I did clone the repository, just not through Eclipse. I'm trying to follow the instructions here--> http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#respository_checkoutproject

Answer (score 0):

Once you clone the git repository, in the Git perspective, right click on the "working directory" node in the git repository view and do "Import projects..." action.  That will bring up a wizard that will let you search the subfolders for .project files and import any existing Eclipse projects.

Comment: But what if I want clone Git repository with eGit, and I also don't have this option?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Juno (3.8) - I don't know what was the way I installed eGit but I think I done this wrong.

I tried to completely remove Eclipse from my Ubuntu 14.04 and reinstall it but eGit still was there...

Finally, remove .eclipse hidden directory from my home folder fixed this issue. Then I installed eGit once again, by select All Available Sites and find it on the list.

Hope it will help anybody :)